# How do you mock a void method that sets a read-only property?

Tags: c#, rhino-mocks

I'm not very familiar with RhinoMocks and I'm trying to break into TDD on a side project of mine. I've been moving along okay until I hit a wall trying to get this behavior under test.

```
    private int _result;
    public int Result { get { return _result; } }

    public void GetRandomValue()
    {
        Random n = new Random();
        _result = n.Next(1,100);
    }
```

Since this is an abstract class, how can I use RhinoMocks to verify that when I call the GetRandomValue method that the Result property is set? Or is this a necessary test? Or a better way to design this small bit of code?

Comment: What dependency would you be looking to mock here? The appropriate one would be the Random (which you almost certainly shouldn't be creating in your method anyway).

Comment: Well, there are good reasons *not* to create a `Random` yourself each time you call `GetRandomValue`... see http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter12/Random.aspx

Comment: For what it's worth, I think what Jon helped me realize is that RandomClass was doing too many things: maintaining state and getting random numbers. I don' see value in abstracting Random out as it would be a class wrapping one object, but I do see value and having GetRandmomValue return a RandomResult and removing the properties from RandomClass. Now everything tests fine and makes a bit more sense to boot. EDIT: I didn't see Jon's link when I posted this, so I may yank Random out after all. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I would go about testing it is

```
var randomizerClass = new RandomizerClass();
ranomizerClass.GetRandomValue();
var result = ranomizerClass.Result;

Assert.IsTrue(result > 0 && result < 101);
```

And the ranomizerClass is the concrete implementation of the abstract class. You don't need to separately test your abstract class since that will be done through the concrete implementation

Comment: I think without abstracting the randomizer to it's own class, this makes the most sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should extract the interface from the abstract class and simply implement the mock for it with corresponding methods?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably when you instantiate the type, the `_result` field is set to it's default value of 0. So can't you just create an instance of the type, call the method, and then check the value of the `Result` property doesn't equal 0?

It seems odd that a method called `GetRandomValue`, doesn't actually return anything. Is there a reason why this method doesn't return the result? Also, I would instantiate your `Random` type outside the scope of the method.

Answer (score 0):

How can you test that you're getting a random number? It's random, so you can't write a test that's actually asserting anything useful. You *could* make an `IRandomNumberProvider` interface and implement it on a `RandomNumberProvider`, then mock that for testing purposes, but you wouldn't be testing anything of value in my opinion. Even if you did like some other folks suggested and asserted that the number is between 1 and 100, you haven't tested anything useful in your code, you've just ensured that Microsoft's implementation of `Next` is working, which is a given.

Your `GetRandomValue()` method shouldn't set `Result`, though. It should *return* the result. Otherwise, you've introduced a side effect into your class, and that generally can cause weird, hard-to-track-down bugs.

Comment: The random number will be used as a lookup value to set several fields. I could (and considered) return an object that's simply a structure of the various return values. Just trying to stick with KISS/YAGNI/etc. I'm not so much interested in testing the random number generation as I am being able to verify that when I call it, the property is getting set with the result. But I see plenty of examples here on how I could do that.

Answer (score 0):

In the cases where you need to test functionality in an abstract class, simply create a class that implements it in your test project.

E.g. given the following class

```
public abstract class MyClass
{
    private int _result;     
    public int Result { get { return _result; } }      
    public void GetRandomValue()     
    {         
        Random n = new Random();         
        _result = n.Next(1,100);     
    }
}
```

Create a test class in your test project

```
public class StubMyClass : MyClass
{ 
}
```

and then test it as follows

```
[Test]
public void ShouldSetResultAfterCallingGetRandomValue()
{ 
    var myClass = new StubMyClass();
    myClass.GetRandomValue();
    int expected = 1234;
    Assert.That(myClass.Result, Is.EqualTo(expected));
}
```